# Symfony How to doing translate jordillonch / CrudGeneratorBundle

Tags: symfony, translation

I have in my template something like that

```
<h1>Workers {{ 'views.index.list'|trans({}, 'JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle') }}</h1>
```

And I want to translate this but I don't know how. I guess have to create a file with translations but where save it ,how name a file and what write inside? 
In app/config/config.yml I have `'translator: { fallback: "%locale%" }'`

In `'symfony/app/config/parameters.yml'` defined locale parameter `"locale:pl"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look at the bundle's [Resources / translations](https://github.com/jordillonch/CrudGeneratorBundle/tree/master/Resources/translations) folder. It looks loke this:

```
JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle.ca.yml
JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle.en.yml
JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle.es.yml
```

Then create a file `JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle.pl.yml` (if you want to translate to the pl local) and put it to the `app/Resources/JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle/translations` directory.

Use one of the default translation files as a pattern for your translation, translate all text you need and save it to the pl translation file you've just created.

See also: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-validation-etc